# I use Steam to log in, how do I use this logon for stackoverflow.com?

Tags: support, openid

There is no option to use Steam for logon on Stackoverflow and logging in with StackExchange Account does not work apparently, because I never created one with this account.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can manually enter the Steam OpenID URL (`http://steamcommunity.com/openid`) by clicking "Show more login options..." and then putting that URL into the box. Then you should be able to log in with Steam normally, and the accounts will be associated automatically.

Alternatively, you can associate another OpenID account with your account on this site by going to your user page and clicking "my logins" at the top. Then you should be able to click "add more logins..." to associate another account with this one. Then you can use that account to log in to stackoverflow.

Comment: I would recommend the second approach. Use your Google credentials, or create a Stack Exchange OpenID.

Comment: Why? I don't really see a problem with using Steam credentials everywhere. The amount of extra work is minimal.

Comment: Just for ease of logging in to other sites on the network.  Yes, using Steam is possible and relatively simple, but it's so much easier to just click on one of the options already present.  Also, if you're already signed into Google and have associated that account with the site you're trying to log into, it's literally just two clicks to log in: hit the log in link, then choose Google.  Painless.

Comment: I'd have to side with murgatroid. Either direction is extra work - some people don't want to have to get separate login systems (and, in fact, half the point behind OpenID is to avoid this very issue) just to access one other site. Steam still works for Stack Exchange, so it ends up being whether the user will see "entering an address" as more work versus "maintaining another login identity". All things said, though... we only have **9** tiny alternate login icons on Stack Overflow...

Comment: I'm partly of the opinion that more options = better.  As can be seen [here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/2866/17529), I've had issues in the past where I had trouble logging in with one provider, yet another provider worked.  Now, to be fair, it was an isolated event, and it actually was Steam that saved my bacon, but if it wasn't for the fact that I had already associated Steam with my account, then I probably wouldn't have been able to log in at all.  Also, if you're already maintaining a Google account (and honestly, who here isn't?), then is it really that much extra work?

Comment: It's true that having more accounts is useful, but that usefulness is orthogonal to the problem in question. Besides, as Grace pointed out, part of the reason for using OpenID is that you don't have to assume that someone has any particular account. Plus, the whole reason I put both options in my post was so that the OP would be able to pick the option that is best for *their* situation.

Comment: For those who haven't logged in since forever, here's what the login page says: "**Why OpenID?** It’s a single username and password that allows you to log in to any OpenID-enabled site."

Comment: That worked, thanks. But yeah, I'd like to have a "Login with Steam" option exchange wide, since they already use it on Arqade.

Comment: The reason that it was added to Arqade is that the number of PC gamers who don't use Steam is basically 0. You are the target audience for the Steam OpenID login, which presumably lowered the barrier to entry. But having Steam as one of the major options for logging in doesn't make sense on many of the other sites within the network. For instance, while Cooking and Home DIY may have some gamers, that is not the primary focus for them. Having a prominent button that never gets clicked doesn't make sense for them. Having said that, it might make sense to add it to the more options list.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense that there's even no small Steam button under "show more login options".

Comment: It would be unreasonable for them to give every possible OpenID provider a button. They had to choose some subset of providers and allow the rest to be entered manually in the text box, and most likely people don't use Steam unless they are on Arqade or they come from Arqade.