# Steam login button is missing from sites other than Arqade

Tags: feature-request, openid, login

On Arqade, there's a button allowing to log in with Steam account. This button is missing from other sites, so users need either to type Steam OpenID address manually or to add another login option. Both options are not really convenient for users coming from Arqade to other SE network sites.

Also, Steam is used very often by game developers, so it would be very useful to have the Steam login button on Gamedev and Stack Overflow.

So, SE team, could you add a button to login with Steam on all sites, at least under "more login options"?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150191/i-use-steam-to-log-in-how-do-i-use-this-logon-for-stackoverflow-com

Answer (score 2):

The solution given on [I use Steam to log in, how do I use this logon for stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150191/i-use-steam-to-log-in-how-do-i-use-this-logon-for-stackoverflow-com) looks fairly sufficient.

You can click on "My logins" on your profile, "Add more logins" and add an additional one to your account, to use on different sites. I don't know many people without Google, Facebook OR Yahoo accounts.