# What are the qualifications needed to participate in a moderator election?

Tags: support, reputation, moderation, election

What are the qualifications needed to participate in a moderator election?

- What badges are required?
- What is the minimum reputation required?
- What are the privileges needed?
- Do you need to have an account on Stack Exchange?
- Are the up down votes considered?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/election/3

Comment: Do you really believe that it would make much sense to run for moderator on a big site such as SO if you just barely meet the requirements? The community is not likely to know you in this case so chances are extremely low anyway.

Comment: I like the fact that you want to actively participate on the site. Moderation is not the only way though. As you gain more reputation, you will gain more privileges which allow you various forms of community moderation. Take your time to discover those principles and once you've been here for a significant amount of time and gained a significant amount of experience, make yourself a candidate.

Comment: @Thief I was sure we have faq for elections, but apparently such thing is not mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Think we should add such?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, [I started one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)! If it can become a proper FAQ that would be great...

Comment: @Ben nice, I did see it in the past but forgot. :)

Comment: @suresh.g If you want renewed attention for your question then adding three dots to it is not the way. Please don't make such trivial edits.

Comment: @Bart - Can you tell me how [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152916/steam-login-button-is-missing-from-sites-other-than-arqade) is bummped in [active tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) by Community ♦ User? (What changes are made by Community ♦ User?)

Comment: @hims056 The community user randomly bumps questions from time to time which are unanswered and inactive to give it some free new attention. It shows up as being responsible for the bump, but does make no changes to the question itself. This is also explained in its profile: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: @Bart - Aah did a lot of research but never seen it's whole profile. :( Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the latest [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3) election, the minimum requirements were (emphasis mine):

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than **3,000 reputation** may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

...and...

> For the Stack Overflow election, an eligible candidate for the election **must have all of the following badges**:
>
> - [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty)
> - [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white)
> - [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy)
> - [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention)

In the other sites of the network, the reputation requirement is 300, and there are no badge requirements, check out the latest [Super User election page](https://superuser.com/election/2) for example. On Beta sites there are no elections, [moderators are appointed directly by Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

These requirements are subject to change at any time at Stack Exchange's discretion. Another requirement that is not immediately obvious is that you will have to abide by the [Moderator Agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement). Even if elected, Stack Exchange may remove your diamond at any time if you don't follow the agreement's terms.

Your meta participation and helpful flags are also very important. Take a look at Yi Jiang's [Moderator Candidate Statistics](http://se.awio.com/election.html), to get a better feeling of what people usually look for in a moderator. To better understand what a moderator's role is, you should also read:

- [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/),
- [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role),
- [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet),
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101431/should-stack-overflow-moderators-have-a-standard-of-duty.

Comment: I guess that "in a good standing" means without any past (or current!) warnings/bans (not post ban, the manual suspension posed by moderators) on his account. Is there is official confirmation to this though?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No. Have a look at [this nominee's](http://stackoverflow.com/election/3#post-10925444) introduction.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't think previous bans necessarily disqualify a candidate, I haven't heard of a case like this. But I know that a current ban falls under the "in good standing" clause and prevents a user from nominating themselves.

Comment: @hims056 thanks, this proves me wrong. Well, I guess "in a good standing" means just not **currently** suspended then.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd AFAIK the "good standing" clause hasn't been enforced (yet). And it's intentionally vague, it's up to SE to decide what it means (and enforce it).

Comment: @Yannis fair enough, thanks!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd btw if someone is currently suspended, the rep requirement will prohibit them from nominating themselves (suspension == rep locked to 1).

Comment: @Yannis yep good point. I wonder though what will happen is a user get suspended while he's already a nominee... :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't think that will ever happen. Moderators would certainly not suspend a candidate, that would generate tons and tons of drama, we'd certainly escalate the issue to SE. And SE would probably remove the nomination before suspending, if they actually decided that the candidate should be suspended.